# PPTP access to lan network

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, lan, pptp

I have a VPN on the ubuntu server. I connect fine but I cannot access the lan network.

Local network: `192.168.2.0/200`
VPN: `192.168.3.100/200`

I need to access to next address to `192.168.2.55`

I try to change `iptables -I FORWARD` and always show me the error `iptables v1.6.1: invalid mask 200 specified`

Answer (score -1):

Your [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) range is invalid.  There is not a /200.  You may be confusing CIDR with a subnet mask.